# Facebook application tab on fan page

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to make an tab application on a fan page. A year ago, using `facebook.php` v.2.0, I was able to create and manage an application, but now the things have changed and I can't figure out how to connect to the API to verify if a fan page is liked or not. I use `facebook.php` v. 3.1.1, so a year ago I would have used:

```
<?php
    require 'facebook.php';
    $app_id = "YOUR APP ID HERE";
    $app_secret = "YOUR SECRET KEY HERE";

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
    ));

    $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
    $like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
?>
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Actually, you can just use `$_POST['signed_request']` - read this http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: Not working .. i think i miss something .. bcause and $user = $facebook->getUser(); is 0 (zero) and echo var_export($_POST['signed_request'], true); is NULL ...

Comment: the app has access to user id and user details only if the user has given the app (at least basic) permissions, just do `print_r( parse_signed_request( $_REQEST['signed_request'], $secret ) );` and see what data you're getting. page->liked is definitely there even if the user has not given app permissions

Comment: it seems that parse_signed_request function doesnt exist ..

Comment: just copy page the "Verifying and Decoding" section from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: i copied the function after the require facebook.php then apealed the function with your print but .. nothing, can be something bag when i created the application?

Comment: you don't need the require, you don't need any SDK, just this function to parse the input, make sure you're using the correct application secret -see below

Comment: possible duplicate of [Seamless way to check if user likes page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5329818/seamless-way-to-check-if-user-likes-page)

Comment: if you are not getting the `signed_request`, most likely you have some kind of redirection! check this [answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9381869/fb-authentication-goes-from-fanpages-to-app-page-and-not-back-to-fanpage/9393822#9393822).

Comment: so i need to authenticate? is not enough to call new Facebook ?

Comment: All code for a minimal app for facebook using sdk 3.1.1 how look like?

Comment: every time i tryed to authenticate i get this error Eroare
An error occurred. Please try again later. with link https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=215673801864574&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpitziworld.ro%2Ffacebook%2Fvizualizari_profil%2F&state=992bbbe00b00e14ad9268ebb180f37c2

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `getSignedRequest`, something like this should work:

```
$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

if (empty($data["page"]["liked"])) {
   //User is not a fan
} else {
  //User is a fan
}
```

Comment: Its every time not fan .. i think when i create the app something was wrong .. look: http://www.facebook.com/PentruRomani?sk=app_215673801864574 when you acces it no permission required

Comment: Also, make sure you have a `/` at the end of your tab URL in your app configuration, it seems that it is problematic sometimes

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
<?php
    $secret = ''; // Input the application secret

    function parse_signed_request( $signed_request, $secret ) {
        list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);

        // Decode the data
        $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
        $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

        if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
            echo 'Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256';
            return null;
        }

        // Check signature
        $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
        if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
            echo 'Bad Signed JSON signature!';
            return null;
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function base64_url_decode($input) {
        return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
    }

    $data = parse_signed_request( $_REQUEST['signed_request'], $secret);
    print_r( $data);
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: write me something on fumezzzz.sentimente@yahoo.com please.

Comment: when i create the app should i gave there some permisions? the secret exists i checked app on facebook and pagetab ...